# How do I subset a data table row in R to get the rows unique to itself

Tags: r, data.table, subset

I know this may be a simple question but I cant seem to get it right.

I have two data tables data table **old_dt** and data table **new_dt**. Both data tables has two similar columns. My goal is to get the rows from new_dt that is not in old_dt.

Here is an example. Old_dt

```
v1 v2
1 a
2 b
3 c
4 d
```

Here is new_dt

```
v1 v2
3 c
4 d
5 e
```

What I want is to get just the 5 e row.

Using **setdiff** didn't work because my real data is more than 3 million rows. Using subset like this

```
sub.cti <- subset(new_dt, old_dt$v1 != new_dt$v1 & old_dt$v2!= new_dt$v2)
```

Only resulted in new_dt itself.

Using

```
sub.cti <- subset(new_dt, old_dt$v1 != new_dt$v1 & old_dt$v2!= new_dt$v2)
```

Reulted in nothing.

Using

```
sub.cti <- new_dt[,.(!old_dt$v1, !old_dt$v2)]
```

Reulted in multiple rows of FALSEs

Can somebody help me?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Using the `%in%` operator in the first argument. `super_new_dt <- new_dt[!(new_dt %in% old_dt), ]` The `in` operator returns a boolean vector based on your condition. It sees if each item in the first argument is "in" the second argument and returns true if one is there, false if none.

Comment: Not sure what you mean about `setdiff` not working. In the CRAN version of the package, there is no `setdiff`, and in the development version, it is available and should work fine.

Comment: @Frank, since my data is very large, it took a very long time for setdiff to finish, I had to terminate the process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can do a `join` (data from @giraffehere's post)

```
df2[!df1, on = "a"]
#   a  b
#1: 6 14
#2: 7 15
```

To get rows in 'df1' that are not in 'df2' based on the 'a' column

```
df1[!df2, on = "a"]
#   a  b
#1: 4  9
#2: 5 10
```

---

In the OP's example we need to join `on` both columns

```
new_dt[!old_dt, on = c("v1", "v2")]
#   v1 v2
#1:  5  e
```

NOTE: Here I assumed the 'new_dt' and 'old_dt' as `data.table`s.

---

Of course, `dplyr` is a good package.  For dealing with this problem, a shorter `anti_join` can be used

```
library(dplyr)
anti_join(new_dt, old_dt)
#     v1    v2
#   (int) (chr)
#1     5     e
```

or the `setdiff` from `dplyr` can work on `data.frame`, `data.table`, `tbl_df` etc.

```
setdiff(new_dt, old_dt)
#   v1 v2
#1:  5  e
```

However, the question is tagged as `data.table`.

Comment: Thanks @akrun, new_dt[!old_dt, on = c("v1", "v2")] works and it very simple!

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I noticed OP wanted both rows and not just one to match on. I'll keep the data initialization part of the solution here as it is referenced above by @akron. However, use the top solution @akrun posted. It is the more of the "data.table way".

```
df1 <- data.table(a = 1:5, b = 6:10)
df2 <- data.table(a = c(1, 2, 3, 6, 7), b = 11:15)
head(df1)


   a  b
1: 1  6
2: 2  7
3: 3  8
4: 4  9
5: 5 10

head(df2)


   a  b
1: 1 11
2: 2 12
3: 3 13
4: 6 14
5: 7 15
```

Answer (score 1):

dplyr would help a lot when you deal with tabular data in R - Would recommend you learn more about dplyr [here](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html)

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr) # this is just for shorter code with %<>%

# Create a sequence number that combine v1 & v2
Old_dt %<>%
  mutate(sequence = paste0(v1,v2))
new_dt %<>%
  mutate(sequence = paste0(v1,v2))

# Filter new_dt by sequence not existed in old_dt
result <- new_dt %>%
  filter(!(sequence %in% Old_dt$sequence)) %>%
  select(v1:v2)

  v1 v2
   5  e
```

Answer (score 0):

If column a has repeats, you could try this base R hack:

```
id.var1 <- paste(df1$a, df1$b,sep="_")
id.var2 <- paste(df2$a, df2$b,sep="_")

dfKeep <- df[!(id.var2 %in% id.var1),]
```